# How to combine 2 objects with same properties-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to merge two JavaScript objects with same properties/keys defined. Just that the values are not duplicate.
For example I'd like to:

```
    var obj1 = { 
0:{id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" },
1: {id: 33, name: 'abc3', date: "12/13/12", type:"131"}
}
var obj2 = { 
0:{id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }
1:{id: 4, name: 'abc4', date: "12/4/12", type:"14"}
}
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q9c8k2yh/
this is the expected structure:

[image]
I want the o/p to be:

```
var obj3 = {
  0: { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" },
1: { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }
}
```

I looked up at the sources online and the most common answer I get:

```
Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
```

I have tried:

```
obj3 = Object.assign(obj2, obj1);//returns { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
obj3 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);//return { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }
obj3 = Object.assign({},obj2, obj1); //return { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
```

but none of them gives me both the objects. I do not want to replace one over the other. is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing is *not* merging them.

Comment: Are you looking to combine them into an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Comment: no I want to maintain its type as Object

Comment: `{0: obj1, 1: obj2}`? If you have a small definite number of them at least.

Comment: You want to clone them or hold references to them?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: clone  them into another object

Comment: @NinaScholz: I have added it in the Q: ```obj3 = {
  0: { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" },
1: { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }
}```

Comment: Thanks all for helping me all way, and so sorry I guess I didnt realize I should have posted this for multiple objects as well(edited the Q). apparently this could be for multiple objects withing those 2 objects, in that case the expected outcome possible would be: ```obj3={
0:{id: 33, name: "abc", date: "12/12/12", type: "11"},
1: {id: 33, name: "abc3", date: "12/13/12", type: "131"},
2:{id: 22, name: "abc1", date: "12/1/13", type: "33"},
4:{id: 4, name: "abc4", date: "12/4/12", type: "14"}
}```, is this possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing looks more like an array than an object. But if you want an Object with numeric keys, well you *can* do that:

```js
var obj1 = { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
var obj2 = { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }

let arr = [obj1, obj2]

// turn array into object:
let obj_all = {...arr}
console.log(obj_all)
```

The new object will hold *references* to the old objects. It's not clear if that's what you are after, or if you want clones.

To make clones you could of course spread the objects:

```js
var obj1 = { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
var obj2 = { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }

let arr = [{...obj1}, {...obj2}]

let obj_all = {...arr}

// changes in original objects have no effect on clones
obj1.id="New Value"
console.log(obj_all)
```

Comment: Just a note: can be done in one line if necessary: `{...[obj1, obj2]}`.

Comment: The on-liner for clones would be `{...[{...obj1}, {...obj2}]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a hash map instead of merging 2 objects:

```
var obj3 = {
  0: obj1,
  1: obj2
}
```

Object.assign merges on top the prior argument, where the first argument is the object to replace, so:

```
Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
```

Replaces `obj2` with itself and `obj1` shallowly merged over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone them easily using object rest spread (ES 2018):

```js
var obj1 = { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
var obj2 = { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: "33" }

var obj3 = {
  0: { ...obj1 },
  1: { ...obj2 }
}

console.log(obj3);
```

Now if you change `obj1` it won't change `obj3["0"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to create a new object having integer values as keys and value as requested object

```
var arrayOfObjects = [obj1, obj2]; //put here object you want to 'merge'

var result = Object.assign({}, arrayOfObjects);
```

Or in case you need a function. It'll look like:

```
function merge(arrayOfObjects){
   return object.assign({}, arrayOfObjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be this. Stringifies the item and parses it so to make deep clone.

```js
var obj1 = { id: 33, name: 'abc', date: "12/12/12", type:"11" }
var obj2 = { id: 22, name: 'abc1', date: "12/1/13", type: {
  id: 3
} }


const mergeWithReference = (...args) => {
 return args.reduce((acc,item,index) => {
  acc[index] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))
  return acc
 }, {})
}


const mergedObj = mergeWithReference(obj1, obj2) 

obj1.id = 85
obj2.type.id = 22

console.log(mergedObj);
```